# Clicking on HTML image, popups up with a window,with a thumbnail selector displaying images

Tags: html

Actually I'm designing a static T-Shirt collection page where I want a user to click on a T-Shirt which results in a popup in the same window, where user can select different colors of the same T-Shirt in the popup itself.

Note: I have the different colors of the T-Shirt images with me , I just want them get displayed in the popup where the user can see them as the different color options for the T-Shirt he clicked.

Comment: Have you researched or made any attempt of doing this or are you expecting developers to do this for you? Display some source code for us to work with and i will be happy to help.

Comment: <div class="product-image-wrapper">
        <div class="single-products">
          <div class="productinfo text-center">
           <img src="images/home/Symbol.jpg" alt="Symbol" />
           <h2>₹350</h2>
           <p>T-Shirt Code: UF02</p>
           <a href="ShoppingDetails.html" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Order Now</a>
          </div>

Comment: Sorry but posting a small part of the html is of no use. Edit your question and paste in your source code, anything related to your question. Until you provide the relevant source code i can't see what you have working so far. Do you have any sort of gallery in place?